# SQL: creating unique id for item with several ids

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I've been pondering this problem for a while and can't find the solution (It might be simple.)

I have a table with two columns which shows which ID's are connected, that is, belonging to the same person.

In this example there are only three individuals, but one of them has three unique IDs.

```
PID      | EPID
---------+--------
10004835 | 10004835
10015375 | 10015375
10015375 | 10019859
10019859 | 10015375
10019859 | 10019859
10019859 | 10000000
10000000 | 10019859
10020104 | 10020104
```

What I want to do is simply to add a column to this table which gives each unique individual a unique code. That is something like

```
PID      | EPID     | NPID
---------+----------+-----
10004835 | 10004835 | 1
10015375 | 10015375 | 2
10015375 | 10019859 | 2
10019859 | 10015375 | 2
10019859 | 10019859 | 2
10019859 | 10000000 | 2
10000000 | 10019859 | 2
10020104 | 10020104 | 3
```

Ps. I'm using sqlite3 so no recursion in answers please.

Edit: Unless I can find a solution which works for SQLITE3 I will have to use MYSQL instead. In that case, does anyone know a solution which includes recursion?

Comment: So if EPID = PID of a different row, that person is considered the same? [What SQL have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Records like (10015375; 10019859) and (10019859; 10015375) look redundant to me? Maybe you should redesign your schema a little, resulting in two fields - ID (unique surrogate key) and EID (any of your current IDs).

Comment: @Arvo It does contain redundancy. But it is the way the woman I'm helping feeds me data (she is as un-tech-savvy as me).

Comment: @N West: You are correct. And I have tried some probably pretty stupid stuff which includes creating helper tables and aliasing and so on. Not worth including here.

Comment: You have a recursive problem, because you have chains of dependencies (10015375 --> 10019859 --> 10000000).  I don't think you are going to find a single query solution for this.

Comment: Thanks. You are probably right. Updated question to include recursive solutions.

Comment: how did you find the related IDs in the first place? can't you change the algorithm that inserts into the table so it includes NPID???

Comment: They are confidential data (my example is bogus though) which I'm not allowed to play around with. So I can't extract it in any different way. What you see there is what I'm going to get. But good question all the same.

Comment: What will the eventual use for this data be, there might be a way to sidestep this problem and use the data directly?

Comment: I'm eventually going to change all occurrences of the old PIDs in many different tables with the new unique PIDs I create. (This is a step in anonymizing data.)

Comment: Why do PID (10015375 and 10019859) share the same NID?

Comment: The line 10015375; 10019859; tells you they are the same person and should have the same new id. Sorry I didn't explain this better in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have an upper limit on how long any connected IDs chain can be, you can self-join the table that many times and get the least (or the greatest) of all the ids:

```
select pid, epid,
  min(t1.epid,
      coalesce(t2.epid, t1.epid),
      coalesce(t3.epid, t1.epid),
      coalesce(t4.epid, t1.epid),
      coalesce(t5.epid, t1.epid)) npid
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.epid = t2.pid and t2.epid not in (t1.epid)
join table t3 on t2.epid = t3.pid and t3.epid not in (t1.epid, t2.epid)
join table t4 on t3.epid = t4.pid and t4.epid not in (t1.epid, t2.epid, t3.epid)
join table t5 on t4.epid = t5.pid and t5.epid not in (t1.epid, t2.epid, t3.epid, t4.epid)
group by pid, epid
```

Comment: Thank you- very kind of you. Will look at and comment on tomorrow (not yet certain how sf accept answer and so on works and I must run now).

Comment: "Error: near "table": syntax error", but it gave me some good ideas and better understanding of SQL. Also think it will help others with a similar problem. (BTW, I've decided do this in Python with the .csv file.)