# SQL cross match IDs to create new cross-platform ID -> how to optimize

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization, amazon-redshift, recursive-query

I have a Redshift table with two columns which shows which ID's are connected, that is, belonging to the same person. I would like to make a mapping (extra column) with a unique person ID using SQL.

The problem is similar to this one: [SQL: creating unique id for item with several ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139072/sql-creating-unique-id-for-item-with-several-ids)

However in my case the ID's in both columns are of a different kind, and therefor the suggested joining solution (t1.epid = t2.pid, etc..) will not work.

In below example there are 4 individual persons using 9 IDs of type 1 and 10 IDs of type 2.

```
ID_type1 | ID_type2 
---------+--------
1        | A
1        | B
2        | C
3        | C
4        | D
4        | E
5        | E
6        | F
7        | G
7        | H
7        | I
8        | I
8        | J
9        | J
9        | B
```

What I am looking for is an extra column with a mapping to a unique ID for the person. The difficulty is in correctly identifying the IDs related to persons like x & z which have multiple IDs of both types. The result could look something this:

```
ID_type1 | ID_type2 | ID_real
---------+---------------------
1        | A        | z
1        | B        | z
2        | C        | y
3        | C        | y
4        | D        | x
4        | E        | x
5        | E        | x
6        | F        | w
7        | G        | z
7        | H        | z
7        | I        | z
8        | I        | z
8        | J        | z
9        | J        | z
9        | B        | z
```

I wrote below query which goes up to 4 loops and does the job for a small dataset, however is struggling with larger sets as the number of rows after joining increase very fast each loop. I am stuck in finding ways to do this more effective / efficient.

```
WITH
T1 AS(
SELECT DISTINCT
       l1.ID_type1 AS ID_type1,
       r1.ID_type1 AS ID_type1_overlap
  FROM      crossmatch_example l1
  LEFT JOIN crossmatch_example r1 USING(ID_type2)
 ORDER BY 1,2
),

T2 AS(
SELECT DISTINCT
       l1.ID_type1,
       r1.ID_type1_overlap
  FROM      T1 l1
  LEFT JOIN T1 r1 on l1.ID_type1_overlap = r1.ID_type1
 ORDER BY 1,2
),

T3 AS(
SELECT DISTINCT
       l1.ID_type1,
       r1.ID_type1_overlap
  FROM      T2 l1
  LEFT JOIN T2 r1 on l1.ID_type1_overlap = r1.ID_type1
 ORDER BY 1,2
),

T4 AS(
SELECT DISTINCT
       l1.ID_type1,
       r1.ID_type1_overlap
  FROM      T3 l1
  LEFT JOIN T3 r1 on l1.ID_type1_overlap = r1.ID_type1
 ORDER BY 1,2
),

mapping AS(
SELECT ID_type1,
       min(ID_type1_overlap) AS mapped
  FROM T4
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY 1
),

output AS(
SELECT DISTINCT
       l1.ID_type1::INT AS ID_type1,
       l1.ID_type2,
       FUNC_SHA1(r1.mapped) AS ID_real
  FROM crossmatch_example l1
  LEFT JOIN mapping       r1 on l1.ID_type1 = r1.ID_type1
 ORDER BY 1,2)

SELECT * FROM output
```

Comment: This type of operation normally uses a recursive CTE, which Redshift does not support.  In your example, you only have to traverse one "link".  However, if you had "9/A, 9/I", your results would be quite different.

Comment: The total traverses is unknown (edited example to reflect that better). Since recursive CTE is not supported I will have to add steps by hand and see when the number of distinct ID_real's does not significantly decrease any further.

Comment: I added my query which does the job for small datasets (see example), however it is really struggling (not working) for large sets (+100k rows). @GordonLinoff any suggestions how to leverage redshift to do this in an efficient/effective way?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called *Transitive Closure*. There are articles about how to implement it in SQL.

This is an example in Spark linq-like dsl https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkTC.scala.

The solution to the problem is iterative, and to fully resolve the graph, you may need to apply more iterations. What can be optimised is the input for each iteration. I remember working on it once, but cannot recall the details.